# Keras: How to make fast predictions with trained network?

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, keras

I built and trained my nn and now it is time to make predictions for the given input data. But I don't know the proper way to make fast predictions with the trained nn. What I am currently doing is loading model every time and making predictions on it. I wonder if there is a way to load the model on memory permanently (for a session) and then make predictions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to use a Jupyter notebook, load your model in one cell and do continouus predictions in subsequent cells.

Another way is to setup a server with Flask and run predictions against a simple API.